# How to get a word count dictionary for each row in Pyspark?

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, count, apache-spark-sql, cpu-word

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: comments_df]

And I'd like to create a new column "word counts" such that for each row (comment) I'd have something like this:

word_counts: `{most: 1, of:1, us:1, have:1}`